# Zooming in browser and element sizes

Tags: html, css

I have menu like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk6d89ye/3/). If in your browser start zoomin (Firefox ctrl+roller on mouse) elements will be enlarging. But not disproportionately. In some steps of zoom last menu element (my text 3) jumps to another row...

How ensure some scale ratio? (Without javascript)

EDIT:
Now I see in chrome with 100% zoom element (my text 3) is on another row but problem is still the same but reversed - if you will zooming element (my text 3) jumps back to row 1...

HTMl:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">my text 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">my text 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">my text 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 298px;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: First off, I don't think what you're seeing is a browser zoom issue. I'm on Chrome 53 and `my text 3` is already on different row without zooming. With zoom, it remains where it started. This is happening because  your floated `<li>` have run out of space withing your containing element's width of `298px`. Basically `<li> * 3 > <ul>`.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that - thx there is update in question. And yes i understand out of space but how fix it? (and i don't mean more width in ul or less padding in a tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a browser zoom feature issue.

You have limited the space in which your **floated** `<li>` can be contained. On my browser the text of each `<li>` takes up approximately `80px`. Each `<li>` is approximately `100px` because you added margin to the right side of each one. So, `100px * 3 = 300px` and your container is only `298px`.

There are multiple solutions to this problem like flexbox, inline-block, etc. but the easiest for you might be to remove the margin from the last `<li>`.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 298px;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
ul li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">my text 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">my text 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">my text 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

But then you end up with extra background blue. To fix this don't set a set width on the `<ul>` and clear the floated elements within the `<ul>` so you can still see the background blue.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* clearfix: clears floats */
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
ul li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">my text 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">my text 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">my text 3</a></li>
</ul>
```